# Reusage of a static stream method not works properly inside foreach-loop

Tags: java

## **Recursive method returns inapropriate stream output of cartessian product inside foreach-loop. Java 8**

I am trying to traverse static method, recursively reusing it, inside foreach-loop. Method accepts Supplier of the given streams and returns stream, combined as Cartesian. Two variants given below (2nd and 1st).

**2nd (desired) variant of code:** (fix/advice required for expected output)

```java
public class Main {
    public static <T> Stream<T> cartesian(BinaryOperator<T> aggregator, Supplier<Stream<T>>... streams) {
        return  Arrays.stream(streams)
                .reduce((s1, s2) ->
                        () -> s1.get().flatMap(t1 -> s2.get().map(t2 -> aggregator.apply(t1, t2))))
                .orElse(Stream::empty).get();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

        Stream<String> result = cartesian((a, b) -> a + b, () -> Stream.of(""), () -> Stream.of(""));
        for (Integer curI : list) {

            result = cartesian(
                    (a, b) -> a + b,
                    () -> cartesian(
                            (a, b) -> a + b,
                            () -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, curI).mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf(c) + ", ")
                    )
            );
            //result.forEach(System.out::println);//also wrong output

        }
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
}
```

**Actual output of 2nd variant:**

```
1,
2,
3,
```

**1st variant. Working with expected output, but not flexible for my needs code:**

```java
public class Main {
    public static  <T> Stream<T> cartesian(BinaryOperator<T> aggregator, Supplier<Stream<T>>... streams) {
        return  Arrays.stream(streams)
                .reduce((s1, s2) ->
                        () -> s1.get().flatMap(t1 -> s2.get().map(t2 -> aggregator.apply(t1, t2))))
                .orElse(Stream::empty).get();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Stream<String> result = cartesian(
                    (a, b) -> a + b,
                    () -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1).mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf(c)+", "),
                    () -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 2).mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf(c)+", "),
                    () -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3).mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf(c))
            );
            result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Expected output for given input for both (1st and 2nd) variants of code:**

```
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2 
1, 1, 3 
1, 2, 1 
1, 2, 2 
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Still reading your code, but this initially looks like an overuse of streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARINIG! Unsafe code! PROBLEM: Stackoveflow Exception raises when number of elements in list used in foreach-loop comes to hundreds or more**

Slight modification needed according to basic concept of Recursion and workaround for Effectively Final Variables in Java inside foreach-loop.

```java
public class Main {
    public static <T> Stream<T> cartesian(BinaryOperator<T> aggregator, Supplier<Stream<T>>... streams) {
        return  Arrays.stream(streams)
                .reduce((s1, s2) ->
                        () -> s1.get().flatMap(t1 -> s2.get().map(t2 -> aggregator.apply(t1, t2))))
                .orElse(Stream::empty).get();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

        Stream<String> result = cartesian((a, b) -> a + b, () -> Stream.of(""), () -> Stream.of(""));
        for (Integer curI : list) {
            Stream<String> resultInner = result;
            result = cartesian(
                    (a, b) -> a + b,
                    () -> cartesian(
                            (a, b) -> a + b,
                            () -> resultInner,
                            () -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, curI).mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf(c) + ", ")
                    )
            );
        }
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, has the issue with last comma in each row output:

```
1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 3, 
1, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 3,
```